# superfish.js seems it is not working properly after wordpress upgarde to 4.6.1

Tags: menus, jquery, theme-options

I'm new to this community.

I have recently upgraded my website from WordPress 3.5.1 to 4.6.1.
It seems the `superfish.js` for my menu doesn't work properly (no smoothing, no delay time). Is there any solution for this problem?

The `theme-scrips.php` (which is called by `functions.php`) is like this:

```
<?php
function my_script() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js', false, '1.6.4');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('modernizr', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/modernizr.js', array('jquery'), '2.0.6');
        wp_enqueue_script('superfish', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/superfish.js', array('jquery'), '1.4.8');
        wp_enqueue_script('easing', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js', array('jquery'), '1.3');
        wp_enqueue_script('prettyPhoto', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js', array('jquery'), '3.1.3');
        wp_enqueue_script('nivo', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js', array('jquery'), '2.5.2');
        wp_enqueue_script('tools', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.tools.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.2.6');
        wp_enqueue_script('loader', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.loader.js', array('jquery'), '1.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('customFormElements', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/custom-form-elements.js', array('jquery'), '1.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('swfobject', get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-includes/js/swfobject.js', array('jquery'), '2.2');
        wp_enqueue_script('cycleAll', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.cycle.all.js', array('jquery'), '2.99');
        wp_enqueue_script('twitter', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.twitter.js', array('jquery'), '1.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('flickr', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.flickrush.js', array('jquery'), '1.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('audiojs', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/audiojs/audio.js', array('jquery'), '1.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_script');
```

In `header.php` the implementation is as follows:

```
jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish({
    delay:       <?php echo of_get_option('sf_delay'); ?>, // one second delay on mouseout 
    animation:   {
        opacity:'<?php echo of_get_option('sf_f_animation'); ?>',
        height:'<?php echo of_get_option('sf_sl_animation'); ?>'
    }, // fade-in and slide-down animation 
    speed:       '<?php echo of_get_option('sf_speed'); ?>', // faster animation speed 
    autoArrows:  <?php echo of_get_option('sf_arrows'); ?>, // generation of arrow mark-up (for submenu) 
    dropShadows: <?php echo of_get_option('sf_shadows'); ?> // drop shadows (for submenu)
});
```

Comment: Can youo show us your implementation?

Comment: @Max Yudin. I apologize for the code appearance above but although I did what is necessary, I could't make it to display as a block according the instructions.

Comment: Check if `jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish()` has all the options in the page HTML source.

Comment: @Max Yudin. Yes. it has: `delay: 1000, animation: {opacity:'show',height:'show'}, speed: 'normal', autoArrows: false, dropShadows: false`

Comment: Have you checked the console for the JS errors?

Comment: In console I get: `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function` in `wpvp-front-end.php`. However, I'm not sure if this error is related since the file deals with video posts.

Comment: `jQuery().on` method is not available in jQuery v.1.6.4 you use. This causes the error in WP Video Posts plugin, and that error is expected to block normal execution of other scripts. I suspect WP Video Posts' scripts are enqueued earlier than yours.

Comment: However all js files were there before the update of WordPress from version 3.5.1 to 4.6.1. Also there are no changes to `theme-scrips.php`. Anyway, I disabled the WP Video Post plugin and in the console I received `Uncaught TypeError: this.on is not a function`. It seems it has no effect.

Comment: That means that you have to not ignore the last (stable) version of jQuery and do not ignore the dependencies. Try to enqueue scripts one by one turning off the others, keeping SuperFish intact. You'll see where the JS conflict belongs to. And watch the console every time.

Comment: I disabled all enqueued scripts (except jquery and superfish). Now, In the console I get the following errors `Uncaught ReferenceError: audiojs is not defined`, `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function`, `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).nivoSlider is not a function` and the problem persists. This problem comes from somewhere else but I can't locate it.

Comment: Something disables `superfish.js` in WordPress 4.6.1 but I can't find it (In WordPress 3.5.1 works fine)

Comment: `jQuery(...).on is not a function` is your problem as was told before. You use the legacy `1.6.4` version of jQuery where this function is not available so blocking the execution of other scripts. Most of the plugins you use require the new version. Don't be a retrograde and do not deregister the version of jQuery coming with the standard WP installation. There is no use doing so until you are going to host your scripts on the different server. The end of discussion here.

Comment: Finally, you were right! After several tests with jquery versions I found that the correct one was the `jquery-1.8.0.min.js`

Comment: Please mark your answer as resolved so the next generation gets to know what's the problem.
  And why not to use the last stable version?

Comment: How can I mark my answer as resolved? Just edit the question title and add [Resolved]?... The jQuery versions after 1.8.0 seem to have problems working in combination with superfish.js (also tested the latest jQuery 3.1.1 with no result). I added this to my answer.

Comment: You've already marked your answer as accepted. See the `check mark` (`tick`) near the answer score. About jQuery: don't go under 1.7.4 in any case. If the plugin requires the version lower, just forget about that plugin.

Comment: OK, Thanks for your help. We can consider this issue as completed/resolved here, if it is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after several tests with jquery versions I found that the correct one was the `jquery-1.8.0.min.js`. Is the only one latest jquery version which is working with `superfish.js`. The jQuery versions after 1.8.0 seem to have problems working in combination with `superfish.js` (also tested the latest jQuery 3.1.1 with no result). So eventually I had to upload the `jquery-1.8.0.min.js` in the `js` directory and modify the `theme-scripts.php` for the file and version of jQuery.